# Angular route api requests to other server

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, routes

Using Angular I have a REST api created. For a while I need to route all requests to api which is on other server without changing all request urls in application.
I have configured server to accept Cross-origin resource sharing. All works perfect when i do single request to server. What I want to do is something like "when doing API request change the request url from /api/people/1 to myapiserver/something/api/people/1"

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a request inceptor on $http for that. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) (section Interceptors)

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      config.url = "myapiserver/"+config.url
      return config || $q.when(config);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```